# My great question is downvoted and wrong answered

Tags: discussion, support, editing, specific-question, down-votes

What should i do?

[That is the question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/375437/instrumental-amplifier-as-a-guitar-preamp), specifiq question on a possibility of making some device.. i tried to stick all the rules: "Instrumental amplifier as a guitar preamp"

But it was downvoted by [user](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/4512/olin-lathrop) because i downvoted his answer as inrelative to the [my previous silly question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/375410/what-is-simpliest-possible-guitar-active-preamp-design), despite his age and reputation. But i read his answers to the end.. and also i had it finally got read the alls of specifications.. on the following device: TL072. HBut he blamed me! Also question was downvoted several times while editing, because of inconsistent formulation. Now it have get that consistence, and also and a target point. But because of reputation, it seems, that it would not see some point in research context.

What should i do? How to delete an inappropriate answer and reset the reputation?

Comment: You can only delete answers and questions you posted

Comment: Maybe it was downvoted because there is no such thing as an instrumental amplifier.

Comment: @ScottSeidman https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_amplifier

Comment: Yes.  Instrumentation is the common word.  Instrumentational is a very, very, uncommon variant, and Instrumental, you word, does not exist in this context.

Answer (score 7):

> What should i do?

You should move on.

Your questions are being downvoted because of your rants and unprofessional comments, not because of some conspiracy or:

(from your prior comments)

> Question seems to be downvoted by this "non-inv-amplifier zealot", and he is suspected to have subcontrolled accounts, or some how else meaningly affect performance, because of High reputation changes, caused by only his impact. Maybe we could review his account for ban, because of instaneous coordinated

I assure you that there is no foundation to:

> how could one man coordinate such a massive -4 downvote in one time on an interesting question? it occured instantly. ehther he have friend people that are acting on his will, either he has bot swarm

This is a professional site. Your posts are being downvoted because of your unprofessional behavior. Nothing more.

Comment: Okay i got it, i would start to act more professional and emotionless. How could i get an answer to that good and rare question?

Comment: I fully agree, my question is good my behaviour is bad. How can i fix that on a particular site?

Comment: @xakepp35 keep in mind that, for someone to have more than 260,000 points of reputation, the person must have helped a lot of people (myself included). Insulting someone like that is not going to help get your questions answered.

Comment: awfuj.. redelete and reanswer

Comment: hey man, i am having fridays and i am getting to solder something..

Comment: i dont know how to write it, its very well non professional, but if whole life would be professional we would be dead

Comment: (sorry i am translating from russian directly dont known english)I just wanted to solder the guitar preamp on weekend. Researched it. One interesting possibility worth research? And i asked the community BEFORE soldering - can i? And i met "the daddy", hey..!!! Get lost! The grave will soon consume him with such numbets or bones coming in grave. Man it definetely stops the motion of progress, i cant express in words. I am happy about his 1980s knowledge, but he blames me i dont read datasheet.. I  AM THAT MAN WHO PERFORM in the STREET with THAT hardware for 3.5Hr on liIon

Comment: @xakepp35 I'm sorry. It is obvious from these comments and your comments elsewhere that you're having quite a lot of problems. I don't think Stack Exchange can help you, maybe you need professional help.